# Limit with L'Hospital with infinite indeterminate formats

Tags: limits

I'm trying to find the limit:
$$\large \lim_{x\to0}(\sin x)^x$$
Whst I did was apply L'Hospital Rule:
$$\large \text{let }y =(\sin x)^x\implies
\ln y=x\ln\sin x$$
$$\large 
\lim_{x\to0}\ln y
=
\lim_{x\to0} x\ln\sin x
=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac x{\frac1{\ln\sin x}}
=
\lim_{x\to0} \frac1{\frac {-\cos x}{(\ln\sin x)^2\sin x}}
=
\lim_{x\to0} (-\tan x )(\ln\sin x)^2
=
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{(\ln\sin x)^2}{\frac1{(-\tan x )}}
=
...
$$
Ultimately it keeps on going, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln\sin x}{\dfrac1x}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}}{-\dfrac1{x^2}}=-\lim_{x\to0}x\cdot \lim_{x\to0}\cos x\cdot\frac1{\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x}$$

Hope you can take it home from here?

Answer (score 1):

if you have $\frac{\log \sin x}{\frac{1}{x}}$ and apply L'Hospital's rule, the log will disappear, so you got to fix it

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\sin x\sim_0 \, x \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \lim_{x\to0}\:(\sin x)^x=\lim_{x\to0}\:x^x.$$

Comment: the problem is that you get $x^x$, which is also indeterminate and requires logging to get a sensible solution, i.e. L'Hospital's type thing. So why do the whole first thing when you can log apply L'H straight away?

Comment: @Alex I thought that the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x^x=1$ is famous enough.

Comment: I'm sure it rivals Pythagoras in fame) but it still is an indeterminate form and requires extra steps to get solved.

Comment: @Alex Yes, but since it is famous we don't have to justify its value. IMO it's up to the OP to clarify whether he can use it or not, only then your point may be justified.

Answer (score 1):

Whgen evaluating the limit of a product with l'Hopital's rule, I'd advise to put in the denominator the simplest factor. So:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0} x\ln\sin x&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\sin x}{1/x}\\
&=-\lim_{x\to0}x^2\cot x\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{\tan x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x}{1+\tan^2x}\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Comment: but wouldn't putting x in numerator cancel it for once and always

Answer (score 1):

Let the desired limit be $L$ then we have $$\begin{aligned}\log L &= \log\left(\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}(\sin x)^{x}\right)\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\log(\sin x)^{x}\text{ (by continuity of log)}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}x\log(\sin x)\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}x\log\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot x\right)\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}x\log\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right) + x\log x\\
&= 0\cdot \log 1 + \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}x\log x\\
&= -\lim_{y \to \infty}\frac{\log y}{y}\text{ (putting }y = 1/x)\\
&= 0\end{aligned}$$ so that the desired limit $L = e^{0} = 1$. Here we have used two standard limits $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1,\,\,\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{a}} = 0$$ for any $a > 0$. We really don't need powerful tools like L'Hospital for such common problems.

Comment: A better way to solve!

Comment: @Aditya: I suggest that you also have a look at my blog posts http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-1.html where I try to present step by step approach to common limit problems.

Comment: I just read all what you taught about limit(possibly except the proofs) at your blog. I am greatly impressed by your way, and now I think all that my teacher taught me was so different; I need to do it all over again; do you suggest any book for theory/questions?

Comment: @Aditya: I don't know about any recent books as I have been out of touch. But I mentioned Hardy's "A Course of Pure Mathematics" in my blog. This is the best book for sure, but it needs good effort on part of student. You should check out the review of the book at http://paramanand.blogspot.com/2005/11/book-review-course-of-pure-mathematics.html

Comment: Actually this ques. was given by my teacher after teaching L'Hospital like "Evaluate using L'Hospital...", ans so i was unsure how to apply it..

Comment: I think other answers have given the way to use L'Hospital and you learn that too. I only try not to use LHR for simple problems because LHR is at a conceptually higher level (involves differentiation and can't be used by a beginner who is learning limits but does not know about differentiation).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Will the Left Hand Limit for this limit exist

Comment: @Maverick: since the function isn't defined for $x<0$, it does not make sense to talk about left hand limit. In such cases follow convention adopted by your textbook / teacher.

Comment: It was given that limit does not exist since the left hand limit is not possible